# removing rows that belong to only one group in a tidy data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
value=c(1,2,6,4,5,6)

group=c(rep('A',3),rep('B',3))

mydata=data.frame(value,group)
```

I want to retain all values in group A and all values less than 6 in group B.  That is, I need to end up with something like this:

```
value=c(1,2,6,4,5)

group=c(rep('A',3),rep('B',2))
```

What I've done so far is to filter group A as is. Filter group B with value <6 and combine the two data frames into one.  Is there a better way to do this using dplyr or any other function?

Answer (score 0):

```
filteredData <- mydata[(mydata$group=='A')|(mydata$value < 6),]
```

This selects all rows where either they are in group A, or the conditions is true, and since nothing is after the $,$ all columns are left untouched from the filtered rows.

Comment: Thanks for the super quick reply.  After running your code I realized I made a mistake in my request.  I added the change into the main question.    What I need is to retain all values in group A and all values less than 6 in group B. I'm sorry about this mistake.

Comment: No worries, mistakes happen. I have updated my answer. It takes all rows where either they are in group A, OR, their value is less than 6. If at least one of those two statements is true, they are kept in the dataframe.

Comment: Fantastic!  Thank you so much!